# active_admin_import with acts-as-taggable-on columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activeadmin, acts-as-taggable-on, active-admin-import

I'm trying to import a CSV for a model that has a few acts-as-taggable-on properties. The tags are comma-separated, so I can write a basic rake task to import a CSV like this

```
CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
        Post.create!({
          :title => row[0],
          :description => row[1],
          :body => row[2],
          :location_list => row[3].split(','),
          :topic_list => row[4].split(',')
        })
end
```

But I'm trying to do this with Active Admin which has a gem already for bulk CSV imports - https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_import

The gem is handling mapping the columns in the database, but my CSV with the comma separated tags for the last 2 columns won't work because there is no "location_list" or "topic_list" column in the Post table since those are in separate tables and managed by the acts-as-taggable-on gem.

I see there are ways to overwrite the  `before_batch_import` and `after_batch_import`, but is there a way to replace the actual batch_import process so it can correctly import the tags?